# Spring security with google Oauth

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth

I have been working on a web application in which I have used Google oauth and Spring MVC. I have implemented the google oauth in which the user is directed to the desired URL if the user is authenticated by the google oauth. For achieving this functionality i have used the google GogleAuthHelper class. Here is my code

```
  package com.mob.googleoauth;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

public final class GoogleAuthHelper {

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = " ";
    /**
     * Callback URI that google will redirect to after successful authentication
     */
    private static final String CALLBACK_URI = "http://localhost:8080/orgchart/oauthRedirect";
    // private static final String HD = " ";

    // start google authentication constants
    private static final Iterable<String> SCOPE = Arrays
            .asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile;https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
                    .split(";"));
    private static final String USER_INFO_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    // end google authentication constants

    private String stateToken;

    private final GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow;

    /**
     * Constructor initializes the Google Authorization Code Flow with CLIENT
     * ID, SECRET, and SCOPE
     */
    public GoogleAuthHelper() {

        System.out.println("google auth helper called");
        flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPE).build();
        flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setApprovalPrompt("force").setAccessType("offline");
//      AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authorizationUrl = flow
//              .newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI)
//              .setApprovalPrompt("force").setAccessType("offline");
        generateStateToken();
    }

    /**
     * Builds a login URL based on client ID, secret, callback URI, and scope
     */
    public String buildLoginUrl() {
        System.out.println("building uri called");
        final GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url = flow
                .newAuthorizationUrl();

        return url.setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI).setState(stateToken).build();
    }

    /**
     * Generates a secure state token
     */
    private void generateStateToken() {
        System.out.println("generated token called");
        SecureRandom sr1 = new SecureRandom();
        // System.out.println(sr1);
        stateToken = "google;" + sr1.nextInt();

    }

    /**
     * Accessor for state token
     */
    public String getStateToken() {
        System.out.println("gettoken called");
        return stateToken;
    }

    /**
     * Expects an Authentication Code, and makes an authenticated request for
     * the user's profile information
     * 
     * @return JSON formatted user profile information
     * @param authCode
     *            authentication code provided by google
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List getUserInfoJson(final String authCode,HttpSession session) throws IOException,
            JSONException {
        List ls = new ArrayList();      
        try{
        System.out.println("getuserinfojson called");
        final GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(authCode)
                .setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI).execute();
        session.setAttribute("userToken", response.getAccessToken());
        final Credential credential = flow.createAndStoreCredential(response,
                null);
        final HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT
                .createRequestFactory(credential);
        // Make an authenticated request
        final GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(USER_INFO_URL);
        final HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
        request.getHeaders().setContentType("application/json");
        final String jsonIdentity = request.execute().parseAsString();
        // System.out.println(jsonIdentity);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonIdentity);

        String email = object.getString("email");
        String name = object.getString("name");
        String picture = object.getString("picture");


        ls.add(email);
        ls.add(name);
        ls.add(picture);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (TokenResponseException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return ls;

    }

}
```

ABove works fine for one time that is authenticating the user and redirecting to the given URL but after that the application is not secure. That is URL in my application are not secure. For this I want to include the spring security along with google oauth. Is there any good detailed example to do that. I have searched the google and have not been successful. I want a good working example for spring security and google oauth. 
thanks for nay help

Answer (score 5):

Here I am giving you few links. It was helpful for me for understanding purpose. Hope it would help you too.
On [this link](http://oauth.net/2/) you can go for your desired category. Considering Spring Security for OAuth, this you can check.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/

http://www.hsc.com/Portals/0/Uploads/Articles/WP_Securing_RESTful_WebServices_OAuth2635406646412464000.pdf

http://porterhead.blogspot.in/2014/05/securing-rest-services-with-spring.html